# Is there a CSS selector for ALL elements in a page?

Tags: css

I am familiar with the asterisk used as a wild card in CSS.

My question is:  **Is there a CSS selector for absolutely ALL (I mean html, body, along with every single descendant, direct or otherwise) elements of a page?**

I have tried:

```
*
{
    color: green; /*Used this just to test and see if it worked, but didn't*/
}
```

Is this possible in CSS?

Please don't ask why I want to do this, LOL :)

Comment: Where, or how, did it fail?

Comment: try adding `!important` to your style set using `*` selector.

Comment: It didn't turn any text green (I didn't specify a color to all elements, that's for sure)

Comment: That should work. Are you trying to override a style?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Universal_selectors

Comment: @Everyone Thanks for the help, guys and/or gals. Sorry for the weird question, but as this question didn't seem to exist on SO maybe it will help someone else, too, in the future (presumably those that don't know about the asterisk selector or the fact that you can use them in combination as descendant selectors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` universal selector *does* select every element, including the root `<html>` element and all of its descendants.

You can also combine them like `* *` which would select the *child* of the root element ( `<body>` ) and all of its descendants and `* * *` to style the next generation and all of its descendants.

Or you can style only the grandchildren and below of a div: `div * * {color: lemonchiffon;}`

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mRSWd/1/)

Comment: Provide info about trying !important (since that's what worked for me, per MarcinJuraszek's suggestion) and you've got yourself an accept.

Comment: Is this compatible across *all* browsers?

Comment: @PolishPrince I thought the asterisk was across all browsers to begin with, it's just that it didn't work when I tried, but !important somehow did, even though the specificity of the declaration should have been enough for most, if not all elements.

Comment: Yes in all modern browsers including IE 7+

Comment: @Lotus, Yeah, I know, that's why I don't understand why that worked... There's no way it was in conflict with EVERY other element on the page. I remembered to clear cache and everything, I don't know why that worked, lol